# Is there a way I can test which one of my VPS's is better?

Tags: vps

Is there any profile tool to tell which VPS I own is better? I have a VPS from rubyringtech & a VPS from burstNET. Both are CentOS 5.6 one is a intel i7 2600 & the other is a Xeon.

Is there any unix software I can use to test to see which one performs better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [UnixBench](http://code.google.com/p/byte-unixbench/) script is a popular benchmarking tool, however, you should keep in mind that your results will vary depending upon what your neighbors are up to when you're using a VPS and your hosting provider will *not* appreciate it if you're running a benchmarking script regularly.